# Passing current node ID to the block template

Tags: nodes, blocks, 8, caching

I have a module with a custom block MyCustomBlock.php that get the nid of the current page and pass the value to the block template:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
$nid = $node->nid->value;
return array(
  'currentnid' => $nid,
);
```

Inside the template I print the passed value {{ currentnid }}, but it only works cleaning the cache! For example, if I load the page with nid 5 it prints 5, but if I move to page with nid 3 it prints 5. Cleaning the cache and reloading page with nid 3 I get the value 3 printed. I think it is a problem with the template caching system in D8, do you have any idea about this?

Comment: If you have page_cache enabled then nothing will help you for anonymous users. If you have only dynamic_page_cache enabled or the user is logged in you should use the cache context as mentioned below or you can use lazy builder(still only for dynamic_page_cache / no cache).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blocks are cached. However blocks are also context-aware in Drupal 8. Per the documentation page regarding Cache Contexts:

> Cache contexts provide a declarative way to create context-dependent
>   variations of something that needs to be cached. By making it
>   declarative, code that creates caches becomes easier to read, and the
>   same logic doesn't need to be repeated in every place where the same
>   context variations are necessary.

The [Cache API](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/cache) documentation page is a good read for everyone.

A Block plugin should implement getCacheContexts. I think that in this case it should either be "route.name" or "url.path". You may need to delve into this a bit more for your particular use case.

```
  public function getCacheContexts() {
    return array('route.name');
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have read the documentation about the cache context and it is quite clear now. In my specific case I have solved using "url.path" as context. It works fine now! @mradcliffe

Comment: See also my response. You can do it like this, but I'd recommend to at least call the parent::getCacheContexts() too and merge those together.

Answer (score 8):

The proper way to do this would be use contexts. Plugin contexts, not cache contexts.

Similar to [NodeType](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Plugin%21Condition%21NodeType.php/8) condition plugin, put something like this in your plugin annotation:

```
* context_definitions = {
*  "node" = @ContextDefinition("entity:node", label = @Translation("Node"))
* }
```

And then get the node using $this->getContextValue('node').

This has two advantages:

- Your block doesn't rely on global state directly. It could for example be used also in page manager, with a different node.
- Drupal automatically understands that your block varies by whatever node is passed in. If using the current node, it will vary by route, if it would e.g. be a node from a static page manager context, it wouldn't. It will also include cache tags, in case the node is changed in a way that would affect your output.

Comment: Thank you, I will try implementing this solution as well and if I will be able to get it works I'll keep it.

Comment: Oh, this is really nice to know! +1

Comment: I tried this method but it stops working overall, the block doesn't seem to execute, I can't even print a string out. Log messages don't say anything and no PHP errors. The marked answer worked for me though.